# TikZ and auto-pst-pdf break Ghostscript

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, ghostscript, auto-pst-pdf

After profiting enormously from other people's questions here, I finally need to ask one myself: since I updated my MiKTeX 2.9 installation a week ago, I can't compile my PhD thesis anymore.

I use `pdflatex` in conjunction with the `auto-pst-pdf` package to include graphics obtained with `matlabfrag`. I also need TikZ for a couple of diagrams and custom chapter and section headings that I programed using the features of the memoir class.

In this configuration, Ghostscript 9.05 (the one included in MiKTeX 2.9) crashes with an irrecoverable error. Here's a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

% (A) alternatively, comment the following two lines
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

% (B) or those two lines in order to prevent the Ghostscript error
\begin{center}
\end{center}

\input{brachistochroneA1.tex}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{brachistochroneA1}

\end{document}
```

The weird thing is that Ghostscript doesn't break if either the TikZ import or the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` block is commented out. (I expect that this also holds for other blocks, but I haven't tested it yet.)

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Also, as an alternative, I tried `pstool` (since the `auto-pst-pdf` manual suggests its use as replacement), but this gives me different trouble: the `\includegraphics{...}` directive takes subdirectories (as usual) with a forward slash `/`, but since I'm on Windows, these need to be translated into backslashes `\` for shell-escape commands. Unfortunately, `pstool` seems not to be doing this, resulting in command line errors when copying the bbl file. (Should I ask this in a separate question?)

Comment: Try `\usepackage{ifpdf}\ifpdf\usepackage{tikz}\fi`.

Comment: Sorry -- that was rather obvious, wasn't it? (Add the sound of someone frenetically slapping himself.) Many thanks, Ulrike! How do I mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
   \usepackage{ifpdf}
    \ifpdf
      \usepackage{tikz}
    \fi
```

Remark: Why the new pgf version breaks in auto-pst-pdf hasn't been analysed yet. So this is more a work-around then a solution.

Comment: it prevents the loading of the PostScript files. I suppose a problem with a redefinition of the `\special` command.

Comment: Thanks for the background information! After 30 hours of trying to isolate the error out of a multitude of package imports and customizations, and a heads-over-heels dive into `auto-pst-pdf.dtx` trying to execute it step-wise in the shell, I'm relieved that my thesis compiles again -- even more though that I now know that it didn't fail because I unknowingly used some deprecated functions. :-)

Comment: @AndreasHäusler: Well, I've been fighting with this for several days and I was about to ask a question right before I saw your OP. It took me a long time to figure out something was not quite right with the latest `tikz`.

Comment: @AndreasHäusler: I have been struggling through those packages for days as well...  Seems the problem still exists...  Took some time to find the right solution as well, but this works as a charm.

Comment: I too have been helped by this, after many hours trimming down my thesis to identify the error and/or in preparation for posting an MWE to tex.SX!