# How to compose a fixed-size image from multiple eps files

Tags: graphics, overlays

I am looking for a way to build an image by overlaying a large `.eps` file (`A.eps`) with a smaller inset (`B.eps`). I want the final image area to have a fixed dimensions (width=`\textwidth`, height=10cm).

First, `A.eps` needs to be scaled to the image area width (i.e. `\textwidth`) and positioned vertically at the bottom of the image area. The original aspect ratio of `A.eps` must be preserved. If the height of the scaled `A.eps` is less than the image area height, I want the whitespace above it preserved. If it is greater, then I want the `A.eps` clipped back to the top of the image area.

Second, I want to inset a much smaller graphic `B.eps` (without scaling) positioned so that the northeast corner of `B.eps` is 0.5cm south and 0.5cm to the west of the northeast corner of the image area.

Lastly, I want to do this for many files where the aspect ratio of both `A.eps` and `B.eps` change. Ideally, I want to define a command and feed the names of the images as arguments.

Ideas?

[image: Schematic of image area]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I don't have a MWE. Nothing I have tried gets close. A combination of the picture and overpic environments gives me the correct image area, but does not clip the image nor give the ability to align B.eps correctly.

So, I am looking for a strategy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably possible to do this without TikZ, but it is quite easy with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz loads graphix

\newcommand\doubleimage[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,10cm);
\node [above right,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0)
  {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}};

% Remove [width=1cm] below, it is there just to scale the images used in the example
\node [below left,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at ([shift={(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]\textwidth,10cm)
  {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#2}};


% the following line is just to show the extent of the image area, it can be removed
\draw [red,thick](current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}}

% adjust margins just to fit both examples on same page
% just for sake of example, of course
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm,hmargin=5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent\doubleimage{example-image-16x10}{example-image-a}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\doubleimage{example-image-10x16}{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I fully agree with Torbjørn. I regularly write documents that have many overlapping images displayed on the page and the best way that I have found to do this is using `tikz`. (I used to do this with word, which was a complete nightmare!)

Comment: Thanks! This answer is perfect! But, since I use auto-pst-pdf and pdflatex I am now encountering this problem: [tikz-and-auto-pst-pdf-break-ghostscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166623/tikz-and-auto-pst-pdf-break-ghostscript). Still looking for a way around this without changing to some other compilation method.