# Beamer auto-pst-pdf -- multiple images

Tags: beamer, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

I tried to include some pictures in a LaTeX Beamer presentation. I used auto-pst-pdf to produce a pdf output.

Strangely, just the first picture shows up in the resulting document. Here's a minimal example. You can find the output messages here: http://pastebin.com/vqmGTXix

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
            \psline(0,0)(1,1)
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
            \psline(1,0)(0,1)
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I ensure that also the second image will be compiled?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would use tikz for the pictures instead of pstricks and auto-pst-pdf. auto-pst-pdf has problems with tikz/pgf (and beamer loads it): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166623/tikz-and-auto-pst-pdf-break-ghostscript, https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/316/

Comment: Thank you Ulrike (I think we "know" each other from mrunix :) ). However, I have a a lot of pstricks images in my presentation and redoing them in tikz is just not an option. For the moment I solved the issue by using XeLaTex, but an easier solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no problem with up-to-date TL2016