# MiKTeX + Pstricks psimages not refreshing

Tags: errors, miktex, pstricks

I beleive I am having the same issua as in the closed discussion: [Beamer auto-pst-pdf -- multiple images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236933/beamer-auto-pst-pdf-multiple-images)

With an updated MiKTeX installation, when I compile my lecture slides (that compiled fine 18 months ago), all ps images are replaced by the very first psimage in the document.

For example, when I compile the following code, both images appearing are exactly the same:

---

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{pstricks}
  \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

   \begin{document}

        \begin{frame}
          \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
          \psline(0,0)(1,1)
          \end{pspicture}
        \end{frame}

      \begin{frame}
          \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
          \psline(1,0)(0,1)
           \end{pspicture}
       \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

The log file is at the following link:

https://pastebin.com/1Y7rwTqZ

Comment: Works fine for me. Your pdftex.def is outdated, run an update with the user version of the update manager and update graphics-def. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375396/miktex-with-pdfpages-first-page-repeated-instead-of-actual-pages-of-original-p

Comment: run it with `xelatex` then you do not need package `auto-pst-pdf`